# Proof by Definition of Intersection, Union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How does one show that the union of the intersection {{a}, {a,b}} = a? I'm trying to apply the definitions of intersection and union to the Kuratowski pair and I'm stuck after the end result is a set who's membership is constrained by multiple quantifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent are:

- $x\in\cap\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$
- $\forall c\in\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}\left[x\in c\right]$
- $x\in\{a\}$ and $x\in\{a,b\}$
- $x\in\{a\}$

This tells us that: $$\cap\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}=\{a\}$$

More directly you can go for:$$\cap\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}=\{a\}\cap\{a,b\}=\{a\}$$

A consequence of this is: $$\cup\cap\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}=\cup\{a\}\tag1$$

Equivalent are:

- $x\in\cup\{a\}$
- $\exists c\in\{a\}\left[x\in c\right]$
- $x\in a$

This tells us that: $$\cup\{a\}=a$$
Combining this with $(1)$ we find: $$\cup\cap\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}=a$$

Comment: Does the fact that I'm assuming that "a" and "b" are sets change anything? I feel like the definition of "cup" here is does not apply to sets of sets?

Comment: By definition: $x\in\cup C\iff x\in c$ for some $c\in C$. Applying that on $C=\{a\}$ you get: $x\in\cup\{a\}\iff x\in c$ for some $c\in\{a\}$. For the $c$ there is only one choice: $c=a$. So you get $x\in\cup\{a\}\iff x\in a$ implying that $\cup\{a\}=a$.